# How to get $request->content in Laravel 5.0?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm new to Laravel and am having some trouble getting hold of the JSON I'm posting to a REST api I'm writing.

**UPDATE**
For clarity, this:

```
    $content = json_decode($request->content);
    var_dump($content);
    exit;
```

Also returns `null`

**Original**

Here's my `store` method:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{       
    // Creates a new user based on the passed JSON
    // I appreciate this wont work as it's json encoded, but this was my
    // last test. 
    // Previously I'd tried: $content = json_decode($request->content);
    // but that was also null :(
    $user = new User();
    $user->name = $request->content["name"];
    $user->email = $request->content['email'];
    $user->password = $request->content['password'];

    var_dump($request); exit;
    // Commit to the database
    $user->save();
}
```

Here's what I'm attempting to send (via: I'm Only Resting client):

```
{
  "name":"Steve Jobs 2",
  "email":"s@trp2.com",
  "password":"something123",
}
```

And here's the result when var_dump is rendered as the response:

```
      protected 'cacheControl' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
  protected 'content' => string '{
  "name":"Steve Jobs 2",
  "email":"s@trp2.com",
  "password":"something123",
}' (length=85)
  protected 'languages' => null
  protected 'charsets' => null
  protected 'encodings' => null
```

So I can see the `content` within the `Request` object, but no matter what I try, it's always null. So my question is, how on earth do I access that?!

Thanks!

Comment: The content is a JSON encoded string. You will need use `json_decode` to create a PHP object

Comment: As stated in the comments above the new User() statement, I have already tried: $content = json_decode($request->content), but that too returns null. :(

Comment: Try `Input::json();`

Comment: try `$request->input('content');`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
{
  "name":"Steve Jobs 2",
  "email":"s@trp2.com",
  "password":"something123",
}
```

Is not valid JSON so Laravel won't be able to decode it.

Remove the trailing comma from here `[...]ng123",`

You'll then be able to use any of the methods mentioned in answers above such as (assuming you're sending your request as application/json)

```
$request->all();
$request->only();
$request->get();
```

If you're not sending the request as application/json, use $request->json()

Comment: You sir, are an absolute star! Thank you, very, very much. Removing the end comma, made EVERYTHING work! I love you.

Answer (score 9):

You might want to use `$request->getContent()`.

Answer (score 2):

Laravel usually decodes your JSON automatically. You can use `input()` to retrieve values:

```
$user = new User();
$user->name = $request->input('name');
$user->email = $request->input('email');
$user->password = $request->input('password');
```

There's even a shorter way, you can just dynamically access your properties on the request method: (this might not work with certain names)

```
$user = new User();
$user->name = $request->name;
$user->email = $request->email;
$user->password = $request->password;
```

Also there are other nice functions available. For example `all()` or `only()` which will return an associative array of all your input values:

```
$inputs = $request->all();
// or
$inputs = $request->only('name', 'email', 'password');
```

Comment: When using these I get: array (size=3)
  'name' => null
  'email' => null
  'password' => null

Comment: Are you sending your request with `Content-Type: .../json`?

Comment: Yup. Have this in the headers box of the client ui: Content-Type: application/json

Comment: Hmm try `$request->json()` for me

Answer (score 0):

Being a protected variable / object, you need to access it with predefined method on the class.

You can use the following.

```
$request->only('name', 'email', 'password')
```

Comment: Unfortunately this also returns null when outputted.